# How do I @Inject a CDI @ApplicationScoped bean into a @RequestScoped JAX-RS bean?

Tags: java, jax-rs, cdi, resteasy

I've added the `@ApplicationScoped` CDI annotation to a simple bean:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class History {
```

And tried to then `@Inject` this into a JAX-RS (resteasy) bean:

```
@RequestScoped
@Path("/history")
public class HistoryAPI {

@Inject
private History history;
```

But history remains null. I've got a `beans.xml` file in WEB-INF. I've tried a lot of variations on this theme, but while the app server (Wildfly) acknowledges it's starting with CDI I can't get the injection to work. Any ideas what I"m missing? Thanks.

ETA: I've tried an empty `beans.xml` and a couple of variants, the latest being:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:weld="http://jboss.org/schema/weld/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/beans_1_0.xsd
                           http://jboss.org/schema/weld/beans http://jboss.org/schema/weld/beans_1_1.xsd">
</beans>
```

Comment: What's the content of the `beans.xml` file?

Comment: I've tried an empty one, and a couple of others including the one in the updated answer.

Comment: Have you tried the example given here -> http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/cdi-adv001.htm ? with the version number 1.1 and the bean-discovery-mode attribute set to all

Comment: <beans ..... version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="all">

Comment: I hadn't, but that didn't work either.

Comment: What container are you running on? Version as well as vendor.

Comment: Wildfly. Latest version, 8beta1.

Comment: maybe configuration: what is the application @ApplicationPath resulting in full app path?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing @RequestScoped from HistoryAPI.

There is a good JAX-RS example in [wildfly-quickstart projects](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/master/tasks-rs)

I tried it on WF8 beta1 and everything gets injected nicely.

Answer (score 0):

strange... i think your code should work...

i have create a example for this question on GitHub (Tested with Wildly 8.2.0.Final and Glassfish 4.1): https://github.com/StefanHeimberg/stackoverflow-20150993

i have it all done without web.xml and without beans.xml

**tested with:**

3 times F5 in a Browser to the url http://localhost:8080/mavenproject1-1.0-SNAPSHOT/webresources/history

**output:**

```
20:32:12,955 SEVERE [com.mycompany.mavenproject1.HistoryAPI] (default task-2) HistoryAPI.init() called
20:32:12,956 SEVERE [com.mycompany.mavenproject1.HistoryAPI] (default task-2) HistoryAPI.doSomething() called
20:32:12,956 SEVERE [com.mycompany.mavenproject1.History] (default task-2)  ===> History.init() called
20:32:12,956 SEVERE [com.mycompany.mavenproject1.History] (default task-2)  ===> History.doSomething() called 
20:36:09,830 SEVERE [com.mycompany.mavenproject1.HistoryAPI] (default task-3) HistoryAPI.init() called
20:36:09,831 SEVERE [com.mycompany.mavenproject1.HistoryAPI] (default task-3) HistoryAPI.doSomething() called
20:36:09,831 SEVERE [com.mycompany.mavenproject1.History] (default task-3)  ===> History.doSomething() called 
20:36:10,549 SEVERE [com.mycompany.mavenproject1.HistoryAPI] (default task-4) HistoryAPI.init() called
20:36:10,549 SEVERE [com.mycompany.mavenproject1.HistoryAPI] (default task-4) HistoryAPI.doSomething() called
20:36:10,549 SEVERE [com.mycompany.mavenproject1.History] (default task-4)  ===> History.doSomething() called
```