# Why i can not add RESTful WebService to my EJB project in Netbeans

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, netbeans, ejb, jax-rs

I try to learn RESTful from [this link](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html#create-services-from-db)

I use **Netbeans 7.4** and when I want to add **RESTful** to my EJB Application I could not find it in the Web Service list. I can see restful within web service list when i use simple web application.

How can I add RESTful web service to Web Service list?
 What is mean of restriction of adding restfull to EJB application?

Comment: Did you look at the required software and resources at the top of the page on your link, and verify that you have met all the requirements (NetBeans Java EE bundle, JDK 7 or 8, Glassfish or WebLogic, etc)?

Comment: @BrianDriscoll yes I use Glassfish 4.0 and Jdk version is 7

Comment: okay, but what about all the other requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a class annotated with @AnnotationPath.

Here i have a working example of a simple Jax-RS Websiervice on GitHub:
https://github.com/StefanHeimberg/stackoverflow-20150993

```
package com.mycompany.mavenproject1;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("webresources")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

}
```

and

```
package com.mycompany.mavenproject1;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@RequestScoped
@Path("history")
public class HistoryAPI {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(HistoryAPI.class.getName());

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        LOG.severe("HistoryAPI.init() called");
    }

    @GET
    public String doSomething() {
        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "HistoryAPI.doSomething() called");
    }

}
```

Comment: And here the link of the origin asked question on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20150993